# TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined`
I want to iterate throw array, to find current id. I guess i can't use `$scope` inside services ? How can i correctly define my `$scope` ?

Objects I am getting from factory ussing http GET method.

```
app.service('sharedService', function (Inventory, User, Tags) {

var allInventories = Inventory.query();
var allTags = Tags.query();
var allUsers = User.query();

return {

    getInventory: function() {
        return allInventories;
    },
    setInventory: function(inventoryValue){
        allInventories = inventoryValue;
    },
    getTags: function() {
        return allTags;
    },
    setTags: function(TagsValue){
        allTags = TagsValue;
    },  
    getUser: function(){
        return AllUsers;
    },
    setUser: function(UserValue){
        allUsers = UserValue;
    },

    findById: function findById($scope, id) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.info.objects.length; i++){
                        if($scope.info.objects[i].id == id){
                            return $scope.info.objects[i];
                        } 
                    }
                    return null;
                }
    };

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the scope you can pass the `Info`  object , that will separate your sevice and the controller .

```
 findById: function findById(info, id) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < info.objects.length; i++){
                        if(info.objects[i].id == id){
                            return info.objects[i];
                        } 
                    }
                    return null;
                }
    };
```

and then in the controller just call this method with the correct parameter,

```
sharedService.findById($scope.info);
```

And make sure you are calling this function inside the `success` event of the `$http` call since you are getting this data from http GET method.